# Converting 3D .obj Files to .jpg image files in C++

Tags: c++, 3d, rendering, vtk

I am working on a project which processes on 3D object Files.
I have lots of 3D .obj files I need to convert them into jpg images.
Can anyone help with the code which I can refer to convert to jpg 
I am using VTK to load 3D .obj files

Comment: What is the question? What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [F3D](https://gitlab.kitware.com/f3d/f3d/tree/master) for this task.

```
f3d yourFile.obj --output=output.png
```

And automate it all with a bash script.

It is based on VTK.